# Why my navbar is not working for small devices?

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css

I'm doing a small project using react, where I needed navbar, so I copied the navbar code from flowbite(that uses Tailwind CSS), I've changed all necessary things need to change for react but still it's not working for small devices. The link is given below:
[Tailwind Navbar](https://flowbite.com/docs/components/navbar)

Comment: Share your Code

Comment: it is better to include your code so we could help

Answer (score 0):

I think it's your browser issue. If you are using Google Chrome, then change your browser to Firefox. Unfortunately, the JS script file of Flowbite is not working on Google Chrome. Checking that navbar on other browsers may solve the problem.